# C# Timer Functions and behavior

Tags: c#, timer

So i'm using a Timer to call a function, however I would like to be able to call this function also myself. The way I thought about was by having the Timer Function call the actual function:

```
public System.Timers.Timer atimer = new System.Timers.Timer();


private void Timer()
        {
            atimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(FunctionCalledByTimer);
            atimer.Interval = 10000;
            atimer.Enabled = true;
        }      

 private void FunctionCalledByTimer(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckOrder();
        }
```

And then if I wanna call the function outside of the timer I used:

```
public void NextPhaseByPlayerInitialized()
        {                              
                atimer.Enabled = false;
                atimer.Enabled = true;
                CheckOrder();                
        }
```

Now the issue that I have with this is that CheckOrder has certain variables that it changes by incrementing them. This works fine if I use the timer it simply increments by one every iterration. However, the odd thing is if I call the function outside the timer ergo manually (also reseting the timer in this process) all the increments that have happened so far from the timer side are set to 0 again.

Its as if everything that is called by the timer is seperate from everything outside the timer and the second i stop the timer the variables go back to their original state. My Question is first of is this intended behavior if so why? And second is there a work around?

Thx in advance for the Help

fullcode:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Programm
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Caller.Init();
        Object.counters[0].Timer();

    }
}

class Caller
{
    public static void Init()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Object.counters.Length; i++)
        {
            Object.counters[i] = new Object.Counter
            {
                currentCount = 0,
                atimer = new System.Timers.Timer()
            };
        }
    }
}

class Input
{
    public void PressButton()
    {
        Object.counters[0].NextPhaseByPlayerInitialized();
    }
}

class Object {

    public static Counter[] counters = new Counter[2];

    public struct Counter
    {
        public int currentCount;
        public System.Timers.Timer atimer;

        public void Timer()
        {
            atimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(FunctionCalledByTimer);
            atimer.Interval = 10000;
            atimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void FunctionCalledByTimer(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckOrder();
        }

        public void NextPhaseByPlayerInitialized()
        {
            atimer.Enabled = false;
            atimer.Enabled = true;
            CheckOrder();
        }
        private void CheckOrder()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("currentCount: {0}", currentCount);
            currentCount++;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind `x = false; x = true;`? The problem with `System.Timers` is that each event is raised on a different thread pool thread, and nothing stops it from firing events concurrently.

Comment: u mean the atimer.Enabled = false? to reset the timer everytime i call the checkorder manually

Comment: It would be a better idea to use a `System.Threading.Timer` here, because [`Timer.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.change?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Timer_Change_System_TimeSpan_System_TimeSpan_) allows you to disable periodic signalling and just postpone the execution as needed. But you still have the issue that the timer might fire on a different thread, and the handler be scheduled for execution as you enter `NextPhaseByPlayerInitialized`. Apart from that, it's impossible to guess what else happens from the code you posted.

Comment: You should post a [mcve].

Comment: But how does the different thread pool thread influence the recorded variable reseting. Like once the interration of one call has happened the changes should be permanent right? So why if calling the same function outside of the timer does it appear as if every call from the timer was not acctually changed. Also is there a workaround?

Comment: now if i call NextPhaseByPlayerInitialized() it should remember the increments that happened from the timer or am I missunderstanding how the timer works?

Comment: Your 'full code' is anything but full. Your problem has something to do with threads and/or instance management. None of that is posted. Write up a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that it might have something to do with the Singletons. I hope this code is now sufficient to show the issue at hand. I apologize for any inconvenience in regards to my prior Code example.

Comment: `Counter` is a struct. Structs are passed by value in C#.

Comment: @GuentherDonner - Your full code isn't a [mcve] so it's not full. I can't run your code and see the issue you're facing.

Comment: Your `class Object` is dangerously close in name to `System.Object`.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:**

1. Never use structs in C#. The only time you can consider using `struct`s is if the `struct` is small and **immutable** (all fields marked `readonly` and never change).
2. Do not use `static` object instances. They are evil.
3. Do not use `public static` object instances. They are really, really evil.

**Long answer:**

`struct` is a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) in C#, meaning that it is passed around by value. This means that, whenever you pass a `struct` variable into a function, it will get a copy of this struct, and operate on the copy inside the body of the function. Once it returns, all changes are gone.

In this case, what happens is a bit different, but still equally sinister: the line where you attach the method in your struct to the timer event actually creates a **copy** of your `struct` and [boxes it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) (allocates a managed heap object which contains a copy of your `struct`).

This means that none of the changes to the field you are seeing, are actually happening to the struct inside your array, except when calling `Object.counters[0].NextPhaseByPlayerInitialized()`, which calls the method on the actual `Object.counters[0]`.

You can rewrite your `CheckOrder` method to see that the timer actually gets its own copy:

```
private void CheckOrder()
{
    // this is working on a boxed copy
    currentCount++;
    Console.WriteLine("this.currentCount: {0}", currentCount);

    // this is the global instance
    Console.WriteLine("counters[0].currentCount: {0}", counters[0].currentCount);
}
```

So, get rid of the structs. Also, if you are writing a game, having timers firing on a different thread is likely a bad idea.

Comment: Thx for the explanation that's what I was looking for. Also the timers are server sided so I need a timer for each client. That's why their are multiple timers firing.